# How synchronization block works?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

**Bug Code**

```
public class Scheduler {
 private Object lock = new Object();

 private int interval;
 private int period;

 public Scheduler(int interval , int period) {
   this.interval = interval;
   this.period = period;
 }

 public synchronized void  setInterval(int interval) {
     this.interval = interval;
 }

 public synchronized void setPeriod(int period) {
       this.period = period;
 }

 public void updateScheduler(int interval , int period) {
    synchronized(lock) {
      setPeriod(period);
      setInterval(interval);
    }
 }

}
```

I have some threadsafe issues in my code to find those , I ran thread safe eclipse plugin in my project.

**Thread Safe Report**

1. Mixed synchronization in Scheduler Class

   Bug Description

   For the avoidance of dataraces, it is important that fields that are accessed concurrently are consistently guarded by a common lock. If the same lock object is not held each time a field is accessed, a datarace can occur.

**Fixed Code**

```
public class Scheduler {
     private Object lock = new Object();

     private int interval;
     private int period;

     public Scheduler(int interval , int period) {
       this.interval = interval;
       this.period = period;
     }

     public void  setInterval(int interval) {
         synchronized(lock) {
            this.interval = interval;
         }
     }

     public void setPeriod(int period) {
          synchronized(lock) {
             this.period = period;
          }
     }

     public void updateScheduler(int interval , int period) {
        synchronized(lock) {
          setPeriod(period);
          setInterval(interval);
        }
     }

    }
```

I tested this code , it works fine. My question is ,  I am invoking **setPeriod** and **setInteval** from inside of **updateScheduler**. When **updateScheduler** is called , the object **lock** is already locked then i am calling **setInterval** and **updateScheduler** but the **lock** was not released. I am expecting the code will end up in dead lock. But , it is not happened why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only one monitor being locked in the fixed code (`lock`), so deadlock isn't possible.

To fix the original code, you could have also synchronised the `updateScheduler` method rather than use the `lock` object. It would achieve the same thing.

In terms of your question, Java locking is "**reentrant**", that means, when a "locked" piece of code tries to "lock" it again (i.e., using the same monitor), it understands its the same monitor and so doesn't block/wait for it to be unlocked. It knows it already "owns" it. Make sense?

Answer (score 3):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1) says

> A thread t may lock a particular monitor multiple times; each unlock reverses the effect of one lock operation.

So you can have nested `synchronized` blocks for the same object.

```
synchronized(lock) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            // ad nauseam and within method calls
        }
    }
}
```

This is further  explaining in the Java tutorial on [Intrisic Locks and Synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

> Recall that a thread cannot acquire a lock owned by another thread.
>   **But a thread can acquire a lock that it already owns.** Allowing a thread to acquire the same lock more than once enables reentrant
>   synchronization. This describes a situation where synchronized code,
>   directly or indirectly, invokes a method that also contains
>   synchronized code, and both sets of code use the same lock. Without
>   reentrant synchronization, synchronized code would have to take many
>   additional precautions to avoid having a thread cause itself to block.